# Paid html5 iphone/android app

Tags: android, iphone, html

I would like to develop an HTML5 app that I could then package and sell on android market and the app store. I also want to make two versions of this app lite (with ads) and pro (paid). When I think about it I have no idea how I can check whether the user has paid for an app (it will be a normal html5 with cache manifest for offline mode). I need to check, because it will be site accessible to everyone.

Is there any mechanism that can trigger db updates in my app when the purchase is complete? E.g. save the apple userid when purchased and then check the userid when the user enters the site...probably not, but you know now what I am looking for.

How should it be handled? Does anyone have good articles/links covering this topic?

Comment: You don't get the Apple user ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still going to need to develop an app for both iPhone and Android if you want to sell something on each of the stores.  The app will be simple in your case, just a WebKit instance pointing toward your HTML5 site.  But the fact you have this app will allow you to track the paid state without gathering user-specific data (which you cannot have).

Good Luck!

Comment: But what if the user will just access my html5 site instead using an app? How can I make sure they do not do that, but buy or use the lite version instead?

Comment: I would create some kind of trusted token generated on the app and sent back to the server, but that is ultimately a design decision you will make.  You could rely on simple obfuscation.  DO not publish the URL and it will be harder for users to directly access it.  They will not see your source URL on your app, just the WebKit window.

Comment: Your strategy is not going to get around that without using some kind of handshake, i.e. a secure token.  Place that on the request via a POST via HTTPS (so it cannot be sniffed) and you will be a lot closer to secure.  You can also check the user-agent on load and make sure it is your app.  Given that you are simply wrapping a website you will probably never be able to 100% secure preventing direct access, but you can get close.

Comment: OK, but I still do not know how to do that. Where do I place it? Do you have any link describing such functionality? An app is just a wrapper, I cannot add there anything more than is accessible via URL, can I?

Comment: This is gtetting into the design of your app, which is hard to do over comments to a post.  Here is some help creating a POST with WebKit which is shared between Android and iOS (the syntax in the sample is iOS).  http://tcninja.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-make-post-request-with-iphone.html  How you handle the POST/Handshake on your app is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Urban Airship has an amazing library for in app purchases. Have you taken a look?

http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/

Comment: But Urban Airship is for native application not HTML5 apps.

Comment: SMH, err, you can always write a js interface, thats why they make Objective-C/JS bridges. You cannot accomplish this task without leverage some native code.